# Nestes ForLoop in HTML - Python

Tags: python, html, django, for-loop, filter

I have 2 `{% for %}` loops in my HTML file one is nested and I can't seem to get them to work.

One is to only display the data of the user that is logged in to my website,
`{% for item in user.Building.all %}` and the other is for a filter functionality I have set up on the same page, `{% for post in item.filter.qs %}`

Small example of HTML:

```
{% if user.Building.all %}
    {% for post in user.Building.all %}
        <tr>
        {{ post.time }}
        {{ post.date }}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Example of Django View for creating data (User specific) - Python:

```
def adddata_building_mobile(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = SheetForm_Building(response.POST, response.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = response.user
            instance.save()
            response.user.Building.add(instance)
            return redirect('sheets')
    else:
        form = SheetForm_Building()

    return render(response, 'sheets/add_data/mobile/add_data_building.html', {'form': form})
```

Example of Django View for listing data (Filter Specific) - Python:

```
class ListData_Building(ListView):
    model = Sheet_Building
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'sheets/individual/list_data_building.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = Sheet_Building_Filter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context
```

The problem is that I can only either get the filter to work where it filters out the data based on what I am choosing it to filter by, **or** it shows only that user's data that is logged in.

I need it to do both.

I tried a bunch of different configurations with the two `for` loops in the HTML but the one above seemed to make the most sense. I even tried to loop through one of the for loops in the views then one in HTML but it still didn't work. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your example code doesn't use `item.filter.qs` so I'm not entirely sure how that fits in & what that is.

Comment: @markwalker in the list view part of what is there requires there to be a forloop with filter.qs and the data inside so when I filter by a field of date for example it will only show the data with that filter value as one of the fields within that 4 loop. It wont run if you put it in any HTML file because it requires several libraries to be installed to function. I'm wondering if there is a specific format that is used for nested for loops in HTML. Thanks!